# Updated vs 2010 solution to 2012. std::function = NULL error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, c++11, std-function

I just imported a 2010 vs solution into 2012.

Now when I compile the program (that successfully compiled on 2010) fails with several errors, for example:

```
 c:\users\frizzlefry\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\menusystem\menusystem\ktext.cpp(288) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty> &std::function<_Fty>::operator =<int>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=void (void),
1>              _Fx=int
1>          ]
```

Going to line 288 in KText.cpp is in this function:

```
void KText::OnKeyUp(SDLKey key, SDLMod mod, Uint16 unicode) {
    IsHeld.Time(500);       //Reset first repeat delay to 500 ms.
    IsHeld.Enable(false);   //Turn off timer to call the IsHeld.OnTime function.
    KeyFunc = NULL;     //LINE 288  //Set keyFunc to NULL 
}
```

I've checked a handful of them and they are all related to setting `std::function<void()> func` to `NULL`.

Clearly I can go through and change a buncha lines but my program is set up in a way that checks:

```
if(func != NULL) func();
```

How can I replace this sort of feature?

Comment: Perhaps `if (func)`? In C++11 `std::function` has a `bool` conversion operator.

Comment: Actually, I apologize, premature question asking.  I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3e30b6e-b8ea-4b9f-b0e6-a20307b36f27/assigning-null-to-stdfunction-objects) after asking.

Comment: Actually in C++11 you should replace all your `NULL` with `nullptr` for type safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer letting the library decide what is the *default-constructed value* for the `function<>` instance:

```
KeyFunc = {}; // uniform initialization (c++11)
// or
KeyFunc = KeyFuncType(); // default construct
```

Demo with asserts: See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b9a8b75e19c5b9)**

```
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    function<int(void)> f = [] { return 42; };

    assert(f);
    assert(42 == f());

    f = nullptr;
    assert(!f);

    f = {};
    assert(!f);
}
```

If your compiler doesn't have the chops for uniform initialization, use a typedef:

```
typedef function<int(void)> Func;

Func f = [] { return 42; };
assert(f);

f = Func();
assert(!f);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you see e.g. [this reference of `std::function` assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D) there is actually no overload that takes anything that can be `NULL` (often a macro defined as `0` in C++). But you *can* assign e.g. `nullptr` to a function object (as per overload 3 in the reference):

```
KeyFunc = nullptr;
```

The same with [comparision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_cmp), use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Or, as suggested by juanchopanza in a comment, use the [`bool` cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool).

Comment: Yes.  This is the answer.  Thank you.  I will chose it in 10 minutes

Comment: I must say... Claiming `NULL` is _general pointer_ is a bit disturbing to me. Then, why did `nullptr` work (because, `nullptr` ***is*** in fact a generic pointer value). `NULL` is not a pointer value.

Comment: @sehe: `NULL` is of course a null pointer _constant_, which is one of those C++ oddities.

Comment: @MSalters `NULL` is implementation defined, and should be _an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero_. On many implementations it has traditionally been an alias for `0`.